# Magento 2.0.7 Product import inserts duplicate entry of stock item

Tags: magento2, product, import

I am using the [FireGento_FastSimpleImport2](https://github.com/firegento/FireGento_FastSimpleImport2)  module to import simple products into my store using the command line. This module passes the array to Magento's core import models. I am facing some issues when importing the products.

1. When I import the products, the import functionality makes duplicate entry instead of updating existing data for the same product in `cataloginventory_stock_item` if product already exists.
2. I have explicitly set the behavior of the import as `add_update`, but when I trace it in the core import model, it is always `append`.
   **EDIT**
   I have traced this issue, strangely, they are not allowing the `add_update` behavior for products, `Magento/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/AbstractEntity::getBehavior()` [metod](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/AbstractEntity.php#L513-L525) filters out that behavior.

**Note**: I am using Magento 2.0.7, and I think the `append` behavior is the cause of duplicate stock items and URL rewrite error.